# Pass credentials to nuget.exe when installing/downloading package on shared CI build server

Tags: nuget, nexus

I have two teams **A** and **B** that shares the same CI build server. Each team also have its own nuget repository in nexus 3 that they can only upload to/download from using their private credentials.

So when team **A** runs a build on the CI build server they should use their credentials to authenticate against the nuget repository they have access to.

But the only way I have found that you can do that is by adding a **source** in the NuGet.Config file with:

https://gist.github.com/xavierdecoster/3205826

```
nuget sources add|update -Name [name] -source [feedUrl] -User [username] -pass [password]
```

But if I do that then both teams can just specify the source name that the other added and then get access to their repository.

How do I prevent that??

I would be really easy if I could just provide the user/pass creds to the install command but that does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't restrict permission on the Nexus Repository Manager level?  I didn't want to assume that could be an answer since you specifically asked about a way in nuget.

Comment: Yes its restricted on nexus as well. But that does not solve the issue of have a machine wide NuGet.Config file that everyone with access to the machine can access and just use the source ID for some other teams repository in their builds.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Azure Pipelines handles it is by creating a temporary `nuget.config` file in a location that is cleaned between builds. Then, use `nuget.exe restore -configfile path\to\nuget.config whatever.sln`